# Display File Names

Tags: powershell

I have to fetch and display a particular file name using [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell).

Assume there are 5 files at a particular Location, I need to display each file name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for the Get-ChildItem cmdlet. To get the file name just select the `BaseName` property:

```
Get-ChildItem 'yourPath' | select BaseName
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer..
 Is there an option to store a file name in variable and display it.
Assume there are 3 files at a location I want to save each file name in a variable and want to display each of it separately..